# still with a continuous tense, is it possible

Tags: continuous

However the covid is spreading fast , I still receive parcels from all over the world
However the covid is spreading fast , I am still receiving  parcels from all over the world

I don't know which one to choose  may be the first one because nothing has changed for me the covid has not affected  the fact of receiving parcels .Am I right?

Comment: However fast the coronavirus is spreading, I still receive parcels from all over the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine.

As is often the case, the difference is not an objective one, but lies in how the speaker wishes to present the temporal nature of the events described.

*I still receive* is normal and neutral. *I am still receiving* emphasises the continuing nature of your receiving parcels. In both cases *still* marks that it hasn't changed with the changing circumstances.

On another subject, you have a run-on sentence, because there is no grammatical relation between your two clauses. Without an inversion in the first clause, *However* reads like a sentence conjunction (like a stronger "but"). I suspect you mean *However fast COVID is speading*, in which *however* acts as a subordinating conjunction, and the whole clause reads as a concessive subordinate clause.